# Keyboard backlight of my laptop doesn't seem to be seen

Tags: keyboard, brightness, backlight

My laptop has an RGB keyboard backlight that i cannot modify.
Currently, at boot, the keyboard goes through a few colours before stopping on blue. Afterwards, shortcuts do not change it, and if the computer goes into sleep, the lights will turn off and not turn back on when woken up.

In short, there is no directory `/sys/class/leds/rgb:kbd_backlight` which there was yesterday, when it did work, and i was able to change the lighting by writing to the "files" `brightness` (0 to 255 value) and `multi_intensity` (3 0 to 255 values).

The only thing i know happened is that this morning, i (at long last) discovered the keybinds to control it, fn+, fn-, fn/ to switch among a few colours and fn* for not-sure-what. However, while playing around with them, the computer froze and i ended up forcing it to shut down after a few minutes.

Trying to boot it back up, it took an abhorently long time, i cannot say how much precisely, but it felt like 10 minutes. I `apt update` + `upgrade`, and the computer at least seems to be working normally.

The laptop's model is "NK70KJ", if needed.

Edit : I have a windows dual boot and just tested on it, the shortcuts do control the lights just fine there.